# linux_startscript.sh: 14: linux_startscript.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to start a multiplayer server on my server. I´ve transferred the files to the server and tried to execute them with these commands:

```
cd /home/user/RisingWorld/
sh linux_startscript.sh
```

but I always get the error

```
linux_startscript.sh: 14: linux_startscript.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I downloaded it from 
http://download.rising-world.net/download.php?type=server&filetype=zip 
and started it on my Windows system, everything works. What did I get wrong?

Comment: You can get more info using the `-x` flag in bash execution: Sample: `bash -x /home/user/RisingWorld/linux_startscript.sh`

Answer (score 3):

The first line of that file shows it's not a `sh` script, but a `bash` script.

I would suggest you make the file executable and treat it as such:

```
chmod a+x linux_startscript.sh
```

From now on you can run it like this:

```
./linux_startscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `sh` points to the `dash` shell:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 giu  6  2013 /bin/sh -> dash
```

You can execute it with:

```
bash linux_startscript.sh
```